# what should be the minimum magnification of the telescope to see properly the cloud(red spot) of jupiter?

Tags: planet

and what should be the minimum focal length of objective lens and focal lens. I've a celestron  which have 300mm focal length of  objective lens and 6/4/12/20 mm of eye piece  but it's hard for me too the jupiter so I asked here "what  should be the minimum magnification of a telescope?"

Comment: Could you edit your question to specify what you want see on Jupiter.

Comment: It's possible you're having trouble using it or configuring it properly.  Suggest you post more info (use "edit" on your question ) and perhaps a photo of what you do see if possible.